# MYSQL multiple grouping error

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, mysql-error-1064

[image]

[image]

please help me to over come from this. why this happen? what is the exact reason?
In my first image i am grouping the sql column by using part_no and its working well.
but in the second image I tried to group using multiple columns, but its giving me an erro as the image. I tried this after change my db values means adding same part no to the both rows and same gp_code to the same row.but its not working.

please help me ASAP. thank you.

Comment: It would be better if you could post query rather than screen shots

Comment: Why there is `()` braces around `group by` ?

Comment: ya thanks sarwar026 thats the case. I used it because I used it many times before, but somehow I got the error now. Thank you very much.
and R.S I put the screenshots because I thought it will be easy to understand for users thus it contains all the relative details about the problem.

Comment: I put my comment as answer since it is the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the braces `()` from `group by` clause. That's the problem.